# redirect_to :back if no HTTP_REFERRER is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I want to redirect_to :back, but there are cases where an HTTP_REFERRER may not be set. In those cases I'd like to fall back to the root_url. I'm trying something like this:

```
redirect_to :back || root_url
```

But that's not quite doing it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Oh, got it. I was close:

```
redirect_to request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] || root_url
```